# Incorrect Expo Modules Version installed

Tags: react-native, expo

The steps to [install Expo](https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/) to your react native project manually can look like this.

```
npx react-native init AwesomeProject
cd *
npx install-expo-modules
```

And your `node_modules/expo-modules-autolinking` will look like this.
[image]

However, when I run `npx install-expo-modules` from my project, `node_modules/expo-modules-autolinking` will look like this:

[image]

## Differences in projects

New Test Project package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "^44.0.4",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.66.4"
}
```

Existing project package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "react-native": "0.64.1",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "expo": ">=44.0.0-* <45.0.0"
}
```

## Problem

This becomes an issue because the `pod install` phase of `npx install-expo-modules` fails with the following error (due to expecting a different directory structure):

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: cannot load such file -- /Users/Ryan/Desktop/Dev/dir/mobile-app/node_modules/expo-modules-autolinking/scripts/ios/autolinking_manager.

 #  from /Users/Ryan/Desktop/Dev/dir/mobile-app/ios/Podfile:1
 #  -------------------------------------------
 >  require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"`), "scripts/autolinking")
 #  require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
 #  -------------------------------------------
Uncaught Error CocoaPodsError: Command `pod install` failed.
```

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution for this? I'm facing the same issue